# Mutable vector: clear reference at given index

Tags: haskell, vector, functional-programming

I understand that the [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.1/) provides a mutable interface which includes the `clear` function, clearing references to all the objects stored in the vector. I can't find a similar function that would clear the reference stored at index `n` in the vector. Is there any way to achieve such a thing, and if not, why?

NB: The function would look something like this:

```
clearAtIndex :: MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> m ()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing like that in the package itself, but one can use the [same implementation as `clear`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/src/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#line-142):

```
clearAtIndex :: MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> m ()
clearAtIndex v n = write v n uninitialised

uninitialised :: a
uninitialised = error "clearAtIndex: uninitialised element"
```

`clear` basically works the same, but uses `set v uninitialised` in order to use possible optimizations.

Comment: I didn't manage to go all the way down the rabbit hole of what `clear` does, and that particular solution didn't cross my mind. Seems absolutely sensible, thanks!